# LEFT() function extracts a number of characters from a string inside where

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

How can build this query?
In the documentation I didn't find any reference to the LEFT function :(

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE
LEFT(CustomerName, 2) = 'An';
to:
await Customers.findOne({
      where: {
          [fn('left', col('CustomerName'), 2)]: 'An' 
      }
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
await Customers.findOne({
      where: {
          CustomerName: {
              [Op.startsWith] : 'An'
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank's!!
The operator `Like`  in start with, works.
```
await Customers.findOne({
      where: {
          CustomerName: {
              [Op.like] : 'An%'
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: but startsWith does not?  like should be just as good, but the documentation does show a startsWith